# Why does my onload handler not work?

Tags: javascript, time

This function should write the time spent on the page to the div.
It was working fine with a window.onbeforeunload alert.. So why isnt this working right?

```
<script>
function tempo1() {
    var d1 = new Date();
    var t_day = d1.getDate();
    var t_hour = d1.getHours();
    var t_min = d1.getMinutes();
    var t_sec = d1.getSeconds();
    alert("Started at--> " + t_day + "days, " + t_hour + ":" + t_min + ":" + t_sec);

    function tempo2() {
        var d2 = new Date();
        var t_day2 = d2.getDate();
        var t_hour2 = d2.getHours();
        var t_min2 = d2.getMinutes();
        var t_sec2 = d2.getSeconds();
        var day = t_day2 - t_day;
        var hour = t_hour2 - t_hour;
        var min = t_min2 - t_min;
        var sec = t_sec2 - t_sec;
        document.getElementById('timespent').innerHTML = "Total--> '+day+'days, '+hour+':'+min+':'+sec";
    }
    setInterval(tempo2(), 500);
}
window.onload = tempo1();
</script>

<div id="timespent">??days, ??:??:??</div>
```

**As a working axemple with a nice working algorithm:**

```
<script>
startTime = new Date();
clockStart = startTime.getTime();
function initStopwatch() {
var NewTime = new Date();
return((NewTime.getTime() - clockStart)/1000);
}
function getSecs() {
var tSecs = Math.round(initStopwatch());
var iSecs = tSecs % 60;
var iMins = Math.round((tSecs-30)/60);
var sSecs ="" + ((iSecs > 9) ? iSecs : "0" + iSecs);
var sMins ="" + ((iMins > 9) ? iMins : "0" + iMins);
document.getElementById('timespent').innerHTML =  sMins+":"+sSecs;
window.setTimeout(getSecs,1000);
}
window.onload=getSecs;
</script>

<div id=timespent></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the line

```
window.onload = tempo1();
```

...you're **calling** the `tempo1` function and assigning its return value to the `load` event on `window`. It's *exactly* the same as `x = foo();`, where `foo` gets called and the return value stored in `x`.

You don't want those `()`, you just want:

```
window.onload = tempo1;
```

...which assigns the function reference, so it will get called when the `load` event occurs.

Similarly, as [Graham points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523980/157247), you're doing the same sort of thing later:

```
setInterval(tempo2(), 500);
```

which should be

```
setInterval(tempo2, 500);
```

There's also a second error, on this line:

```
document.getElementById('timespent').innerHTML = "Total--> '+day+'days, '+hour+':'+min+':'+sec";
```

There, you're quoting the string using double quotes (`"`), but you're using *single* quotes when trying to substitute in the `days`, `hour`, `min`, and `sec` variables. You need to be consistent about which quote you use to start and end a string. Either is fine, but you have to pick one, so either all doubles:

```
document.getElementById('timespent').innerHTML = "Total--> "+day+"days, "+hour+":"+min+":"+sec";
```

or all singles:

```
document.getElementById('timespent').innerHTML = 'Total--> '+day+'days, '+hour+':'+min+':'+sec';
```

---

Note that you don't need to wait for the `load` event, though. If you put your script at the bottom of the page (or anywhere *below* the "timespent" `div` — even immediately below it), you can just call `tempo1` directly. The `load` event of the `window` object happens *very* late in the page load cycle, after all external resources (including all images) are loaded. If that's what you want, great, but if not you have an alternative.

References:

- [Google engineers on when you can access DOM elements](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)
- [YUI Best Practices to Speed Up Your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Comment: but still.. im getting only "Total--> '+day+'days, '+hour+':'+min+':'+sec" in the div. Its lacking the actual values..

Comment: @jony: That's an unrelated error in the code, I've updated my answer. Your best bet with these things is to really look at the code and understand what it's doing, as with the `x = foo();` example.

Comment: thanks! it is writing the values on the div every 0.5s. Now i just need to improve the algorithm to calculate the time.

Answer (score 3):

Further to the above answer, you are also executing your second function directly rather than passing it to `setInterval`. Do

```
setInterval(tempo2, 500);
```

instead and this will be executed every 0.5 sec.

Comment: absolutely right, im still learning so i sometimes miss things like that